# Spring AOP - Appropriate for converting relative paths to absolute paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, aop, spring-aop

### The Problem

In our database we store relative file paths. In our application, the known root directory plus the relative paths gives the actual full path.

As a utility, a Spring managed bean takes a file and gives back the absolute path. I'd prefer if the file could just know it's own full path when we pull it from the database (using Spring Data MongoDB).

### The Proposal

I'm considering adding an aspect *after* all my data access calls which would initialize a `transient absolutePath` property on all file objects.

### The Question

Is this correct usage of AOP or is it a hack?

Are there any better ways to do this using Spring patterns?